# Make div container containing multicolumn elements expand to width of columns

Tags: html, css, layout, multiple-columns

I have a number of inline-block elements that contain multicolumn elements within them. The inline-block elements are contained within a nowrap container, with the intent that these scroll horizontally.

The columns are fixed height (so, variable number of columns). However, it looks like the width of each inline-block element is only the width of one column in IE10, and the width of the visible container in Chrome, so some of the columns overlap. Is there a way to get each of the inline-block elements to take up its full width (i.e. the width of the columns) so there is no overlap?

```
.outerWrapper {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.innerWrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: normal;
}

.columns {
    -webkit-column-width: 100px;
    column-width: 100px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ts9xg/

Comment: wow. i know this comment isn't useful, but this is a really interesting problem.

Comment: so, in chrome, the width of `.innerWrapper` appears to be determined by how its content fills the container **without** `column-width` applied and **then** applies `column-width` and doesn't readjust... just documenting this piece for my own reference.

Comment: Also, in Chrome 33, the `.outerWrapper` expands 7K+px height, despite `.innerWrapper` and `.columns` all remains 500px height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I was able to accomplish this by programmatically setting the width of the containers of the CSS3 columns to their scrollWidth:

```
$(".parent").each(function() {
    $(this).width(this.scrollWidth);
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ts9xg/11/ (columns no longer overlap)

Comment: I am having a similar issue, but I am trying to make it work in a responsive design. Have you found any more information about why this happens?

Answer (score -1):

I would like to suggest use table for the layouting. Or you can use table properties to DIV elements. Below is the example given.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="containerRow">
    <div class="col1">
        This is column 1
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
        This is column 2
    </div>
    <div class="col3">
        This is column 3
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{border:1px red solid;display:table;table-layout:fixed;}
.containerRow{display:table-row;}
.containerRow > div{display:table-cell;min-height:200px;border:1px green solid;}
.col1{width:100px;}
.col2{width:150px;}
.col3{width:100px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/murli2308/Un4bZ/1/

I think you need the structure like this...

If you are good in tables.. You can use table layouts also...

Comment: Unfortunately, the number of columns is variable, i.e. I don't know how many columns there will be beforehand.

Comment: It will work i think if you know the width of each column.. If you be more clear on your question.. then I can suggest you good answer... You want " width of outer container == sum of width of columns" right?

Comment: That's correct. I know the width of each column but not the number of columns - I have a block of text of variable length.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear - the columns are fixed height, so I need extra text to roll over to subsequent columns. http://jsfiddle.net/Un4bZ/2/

Comment: You can use CSS coulumn layout.. Here is the link of example if you want to support only latest browsers - http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_column-count